# Debounce Scrolling with Scroll direction

Tags: jquery, scroll, debouncing

I'm looking for a way to get the direction of a scroll on a debounced scroll event.  So far, I can debounce the scroll, but it's not firing my conditional up/down script.

```
var el = $(window);
            lastY = el.scrollTop();
            el.on('scroll', debounce(function(e) {

            $('body').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
                 if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                     //scroll down
                     scrolldown();
                     console.log('Down');
                 }else {
                     //scroll up
                     scrollup();
                     console.log('Up');
                 }
                 //prevent page fom scrolling
                 return false;
             });

             //IE, Opera, Safari
             $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
                 if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                     //scroll down
                     scrolldown();
                     console.log('Down');
                 }else {
                     //scroll up
                     scrollup();
                     console.log('Up');
                 }

                 //prevent page fom scrolling
                 return false;
             });

            }, 200));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not add the event listener to the `body` here so I added it to a `#wrapper`

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

var onScroll = debounce(function(direction) {
  if (direction == false) {
   console.log('Scrolling down');
  } else {
   console.log('Scrolling up');
  }
}, 200, true);

$('#wrapper').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var delta;
  if (event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
  } else {
    delta = -1 * event.deltaY;
  }

  onScroll(delta >= 0);
});
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"><div>
```